# Swift3: I would like to function read and count QR code

Tags: ios, swift3, count, xcode8, qr-code

I’m building a QR code reader app. I wrote a function to read and count QR codes. I can display the count for dynamic button title; however, the QR code value is not counted like 1, 2, 3. Display natural  QR value.

My ViewController:

```
class LentScanViewController: QRScannerViewController {

var device_name = ""
var countNum = 0

@IBOutlet weak var LentButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func lentButton(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toLentTable",sender: device_name)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {


    if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
        return
    }

    let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

    if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {

        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

        if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
            device_name = metadataObj.stringValue

            countNum = countNum + 1
            LentButton.setTitle(String(countNum) + "Lent", for:[])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try :

```
var qrCodes:[String] = [] // declare it as member variable in the class
```

Then call

```
if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
    let device_name = metadataObj.stringValue
    if !qrCodes.contains(device_name!) {
        qrCodes.append(device_name!)
    }
    countNum = countNum + 1
    messageLabel.text = String(countNum) + "Lent"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. but this code is display metadataObj value. i want to if scaned one QR code display 1. one more scaned display 2.

Comment: It's like this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zKMyp17Squ8&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Edited the answer. Please check.